# Wikipedia API giving wrong page after a keyword search

Tags: python, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

So I've made a command for my discord bot to research a Wikipedia page based on a string :

```py
import requests
import json
import discord
from datetime import datetime, timezone

def getWiki(search):
    data = {
        'action': 'query',
        'format': 'json',
        'formatversion': 2,
        'inprop': 'url',
        'prop': 'extracts|pageimages|revisions|info',
        'exintro': True,
        'explaintext': True,
        'piprop': 'original',
        'rvprop': 'timestamp',
        'generator': 'search',
        'gsrsearch': search
    }
    response = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php', params=data)
    jsonData = json.loads(response.text)

    pageData = jsonData['query']['pages'][0]
    title = pageData['title']
    summary = pageData['extract']
    pageUrl = pageData.get('fullurl', '')
    timestamp = pageData['revisions'][0]['timestamp']
    timestamp = datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
    timestamp = timestamp.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
    embed = discord.Embed(description=summary, timestamp= timestamp, colour=0xeeeeee)
    embed.set_author(name=title, url=pageUrl, icon_url='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a7/Wikipedia_logo_v3.svg/2048px-Wikipedia_logo_v3.svg.png')
    embed.set_footer(text='Dernière révision')

    wikiObject = {
        'title': title,
        'summary': summary,
        'embed': embed
    }

    if pageData.get('original'):
        pageImage = pageData['original']
        if pageImage.get('source'):
            imageUrl = pageImage['source']
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=imageUrl)
            wikiObject['imageUrl'] = imageUrl
    
    return wikiObject
```

However, the results are very strange. For example, when searching for Kim Kardashian (which is the exact name of her page) it gives me the page of Robert Kardashian... Is there something I can do about it ?

You can see that on the website she's the top result :
[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the network calls being made when manually searching for “Kim Kardashian”? Do those match with the calls you’re making from the bot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jsonData['query']['pages']` is ordered by page ID, not by search relevance. This is a limitation of using generators. You need to use the `index` property to find the actual first search result:

```
results = jsonData['query']['pages']
results.sort(key = lambda x: x.get('index'))
pageData = results[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @AbhijitSarkar, by looking at the networks calls, I figured out that it was using https://en.wikipedia.org/w/rest.php/v1/search/title?q=Kim+Kardashian&limit=10 to search for the results. I then edited my code this way:

```py
response = requests.get(f'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/rest.php/v1/search/title?q={search}&limit=1')
jsonData = json.loads(response.text)
searchResult = jsonData['pages'][0]['title']

data = {
    'action': 'query',
    'format': 'json',
    'formatversion': 2,
    'inprop': 'url',
    'prop': 'extracts|pageimages|revisions|info',
    'exintro': True,
    'explaintext': True,
    'piprop': 'original',
    'rvprop': 'timestamp',
    'titles': searchResult
}

response = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php', params=data)
jsonData = json.loads(response.text)
```

I first find the title with the first request then use `searchResult` to make a query by title this time using `'titles': searchResult` in the data object.